# Could not get unknown property 'RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD' for SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debugY

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, passwords, apk

I've been having this problem recently as I'm searching everywhere, also here in stack, I see a lot of different answers.
Does anybody know how to solve this one?

> Error:(46, 0) Could not get unknown property 'RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD'
>   for SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug, storeFile=C:\Users\— Shahab
>   —\Desktop\master\TMessagesProj\config\release.keystore,
>   storePassword=android, keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android,
>   storeType=C:\Users\— Shahab
>   —\Desktop\master\TMessagesProj\config\release.keystore,
>   v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true} of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig. Open File

Answer (score 30):

Make sure that you have added the below line in your build.gradle file @ android/app.

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

Comment: Funny that I have that and it gives me errors

Answer (score 11):

Can you share your build gradle file?
It seems that there is some problem in your Signing Configs.

Sharing a demo Signing Config code.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('demo.jks')
        storePassword "demo123"
        keyAlias "demo"
        keyPassword "demo123"
    }
}
```

Comment: You know when i open android studio, i get this error on the project and also when i wanr to build the project, there is no release or debug option to choose from and I click finish and i get the ; Missing Gradle Project Information. Please check if the IDE successfully synchronized its state with the Gradle Project Model.; these two are related somehow I guess.

Comment: @Michael Are you able to create new project successfully? I think there is some problem in your IDE. Maybe it is not setup correctly.

Comment: Yes, making new project is totally ok. And it builds it. Yeah as u mentioned also it was not setup correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in your app/build.gradle at the top of android {...}

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[androidS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yjRd.jpg)

Try adding this signature data to gradle.properties:

```
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD = 123456

RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS = releaseKey

RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD = 123456

RELEASE_STORE_FILE = key/releaseKey.jks
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently face the same error and tried all the solutions in here none worked until I changed entire app/build.gradle with the following code:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.samwit.ezhealth"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

most importantly is to make sure your targetSdkVersion and your compileSdkVersion are the same also the kotlinversion must be the latest.